how to implement testing a mui icon inside a data string in react?
I have the following function that returns a JSX data string that includes a MUI v5 icon. How can I test the result?


import NavigateNextIcon from '@mui/icons-material/NavigateNext';

export const renderDataString = ()=> {
const sagmentA = 'sagmentA'
const sagmentA = 'sagmentB'
  return (
      <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
        {sagmentA} <NavigateNextIcon /> {sagmentA}
      </Box>
    );
}





it('should check the data string data', () => {
const mockedExpectedReults = <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
{sagmentA} <NavigateNextIcon /> {sagmentA}
</Box>
const result = renderDataString();
expect(result).toEqual(??);
});



